# Uploadfy with Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, uploadify

i'm implementing some upload script with Uploadfy on my site.

This is the script sample i have in PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <?php $timestamp = time();?>
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
                'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
                'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                    alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But i want this working in classic ASP!

I know i need to change these lines to make this work:

```
'formData'     : {
                    'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                    'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                },
```

But i don't know how to change this to classic ASP. What i need to do??

Answer (score 2):

formData are the datas to send to your url for upload

you also need to change the line

```
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
```

by

```
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.asp',
```

and implements the upload in your uploadify.asp page

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that what you're trying to do is to call the php script "uploadify.php" with variables in your asp page.

the timestamp variable and md5 function don't come ready made in Classic ASP, you'll need to write your own.  For timestamp the following should work

```
<% timestamp = year(now) & right("0" & month(now),2) & right("0" & day(now),2) & right("0" & hour(now),2) & right("0" & minute(now),2) & right("0" & second(now),2) %>
```

The MD5 function is rather more complex, but there's [one here which you can download and use](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2366).

Once all this is in place - replace `<?php echo $timestamp;?>` with `<%=timestamp%>`
and
`<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>` with `<%=md5("unique_salt"&timestamp)%>`

Comment: nice answer too.. but i resolve this removing the formData on my html script page, and on "uploadfy.php" i have comented the line that cheks this "timestamp" variable. And works fine with my asp/html page with the script under PHP language!